# Angular 4 with Plotly

Tags: angular

I am trying to build an angular 4 application that needs graph.

I am planning to use *plotly*, but I am not getting any clear site showing the steps or the way to include *plotly.js* file in angular 4 application.

Can somebody please give me some insight on this?

Comment: Seems to be an issue listed here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/955 with a work around solution posted here: https://damienbod.com/2016/04/21/creating-an-angular-2-component-for-plotly/

Comment: You are talking about angular 2, I need for angular 4.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45352071/plotly-in-angular-4-not-finding-html-element-with-ngif. I can see someone posting some question here. Is there a way we can contact this person ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is what I do, first is to install plotly.js using NPM(or any package manager that you use):

```sh
npm install plotly.js --save
npm install @types/plotly.js --save
```

Note: you may consider installing @types in [dev section (--save-dev)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40600860/777285)

Then I edited `src/tsconfig.app.json` to include this, under `compilerOptions`:

```js
    "types": [
      "plotly.js"
    ],"paths": {
      "plotly.js": [
        "../node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly-basic.js"
      ]
    }
```

Then you can use Plotly.js in any of your component by importing like this:

```js
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js';
import {Config, Data, Layout} from 'plotly.js';
```

Comment: It seems that it is not needed to include plotly js file into `compilerOptions` manually, because of the application on tree shaking provided from webpack, which is internally used in Angular 2+.

Comment: If your are having issues after upgrading to Angular 6 read this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213078/setting-up-plotly-js-in-angular-6-0-0-issues)

Answer (score 10):

There is now an [official Angular wrapper for plot.ly](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js)

```
npm install angular-plotly.js plotly.js
```

Add plotly to your main app module:

```
import { PlotlyModule } from 'angular-plotly.js';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, PlotlyModule],
    ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Can then add the graph to a component like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'plotly-example',
    template: '<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout"></plotly-plot>',
})
export class PlotlyExampleComponent {
    public graph = {
        data: [
            { x: [1, 2, 3], y: [2, 6, 3], type: 'scatter', mode: 'lines+points', marker: {color: 'red'} },
            { x: [1, 2, 3], y: [2, 5, 3], type: 'bar' },
        ],
        layout: {width: 320, height: 240, title: 'A Fancy Plot'}
    };
}
```

Comment: @carkod Imagine you have already solved this but looking at the public API I would assume you should expect to change the entire array reference. Meaning even if you "just" change an element in the array you need to clone the array. You can do this easily with `slice()`. So if `graph.data` changed above you could simply do `graph.data = graph.data.slice()`.

Comment: Note that cloning the array can also be done with `graph.data = Array.from(graph.data)`. While it's really a stylistic thing I find it more clearly conveys "I want a copy of this array"

Comment: @Koslun it's an official ?

Comment: @hoangk yes, it's an official library from plot.ly. Meaning it's supported by plot.ly themselves rather than one or more community members.