# Plotly.js Angular 4 how to import plotlyjs-cartesian bundle for histogram chart?

Tags: angular, typescript, histogram, plotly

I'm using Angular 4 to develop a Web app. I got `Plotly.js` imported successfully based on this [post (Angular 4 with Plotly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48347425/angular-4-with-plotly)

The `plotly.js` basic bundle works fine with the line charts. But
I can't get the Histogram and 2d density plots to work in typescript. I suspect that I need to import plotlyjs-cartesian bundle.

Output Example

[image]

This is my `component.ts` based on [plot.ly/javascript/histograms](https://plot.ly/javascript/histograms/) but in Typescript.

```
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js';
import {
    Config,
    Data,
    Layout
} from 'plotly.js';

@Component({
    ...
})
export class ChartComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {
        let x = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            x[i] = Math.random();
        }
        const trace = {
            x: x,
            type: 'histogram',
        };
        const data = [trace];
        Plotly.newPlot('myPlotlyDiv', data);
    }
}
```

This is my `tsconfig.app.json`, "compilerOptions"

```
    "types": [
      "plotly.js"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "plotly.js": [
        "../node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly-basic.js"
      ]
    }
```

I have tried adding "../node_modules/plotly.js/dist/plotly-cartesian.js" after plotly-basic.js but that doesn't work either.

Any suggestion on importing plotlyjs-cartesian bundle for Histogram, Histogram2d charts in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. Instead of using the `plotly-basic.min.js` bundle, I changed to use `plotly.min.js` in both `angular-cli.json` and `tsconfig.app.json`. The 2D Histogram Contour Plot with Histogram subplots came up nicely in Angular 4/5, Typescript code.