# Import Plotly.js in Angular

Tags: javascript, typescript, plotly

I followed the instructions from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48367597/4314952) to integrate plotly in the application.

Unfortunately I experience typescript errors, when trying out the standard examples of plotly.js. The argument types of `Plotly.newPlot(...)` seem to be not correct.

[image]

Here is my component:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js';
import {Config, Data, Layout} from 'plotly.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabs',
  templateUrl: './tabs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabs.component.css']
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    let y0 = [];
    let y1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      y0[i] = Math.random();
      y1[i] = Math.random() + 1;
    }
    var trace1 = {
      y: y0,
      type: 'box'
    };
    let trace2 = {
      y: y1,
      type: 'box'
    };

    let data = [trace1, trace2];
    Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
  }
}
```

I use plotly.js@1.37.1 and angular v6.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the following workaround.

- store Plotly.js in assets folder manually
- import the script in `angular.json`: 
  `"scripts": [src/assets/scripts/plotlyjs/plotly.js"]`
- add `declare const Plotly` right under the import statements in the component where you want to use plotly

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to put Plotly in **angular.json** simply import like this.

```
import * as Plotly from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly.js';
import {Config, Data, Layout} from 'plotly.js/dist/plotly.js';
```